# How to invoke variables from other function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a login function with a return statement. I need multiple return statements the code stops after the first one. I've divided my function into multiple functions. How can i invoke the values of variables, a loop or a return statement in another function? (i allready use some global functions)

i have now made a functions to compare user password en username, with a return statement. then a function to throw an error message when user puts in wrong input and then a function to redirect user when to a suspended page when user is suspended or to the welcome page.

I know i can invoke the function with the name within the function, but how can i invoke just a small part of another function? Or is there a way to fix the (!userIsKnown) statement within the current function?

```
function validate() {
// get username & password  
  const usernameInput = document.getElementById('username') as HTMLInputElement;
  const validatePassword = document.getElementById('password') as HTMLInputElement;

// loop through users 

  const users: User[] = loadUsers();
  // userIsKnown is altijd false aan het begin want bij true logt die in
  let userIsKnown = false;

  for (let i: number = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].password === validatePassword.value &&
      users[i].username === usernameInput.value) {
      userIsKnown = true;
      let value: number = users[i].id

      localStorage.setItem(KEY, value.toString());

      // go to welcome page
      window.location.href = `welkom.html?type=login&id=${users[i].id}`;

      if (!userIsKnown) {
        // when user is not known throw error (is not working because else if statement 
         below)
          const error = document.getElementById('errorLogin')
          errorAlert("Wachtwoord en/of gebruikersnaam is onjuist", error)
      } // go to suspended page when user is suspended
        else if (users[i].suspended === true) { 
        window.location.href = `suspended.html?type=login`;
        return
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Here is something i've tried to invoke the values from another function (i now they look really dumb but i really don't know

```
function loginError() {
  loginUser()
  if (userIsKnown === false) {
    console.log("userIsKnown")
    document.getElementById('falseLogin')!.style.visibility = 'visible';
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('falseLogin')!.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    }, 2500);
  }
}
loginError()
```

and:

```
function loginSuspended(let i: number = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  if (users[i].suspended === true) {
    window.location.href = `suspended.html?type=login`;
  }
  if (users[i].suspended === false) {
    window.location.href = `welkom.html?type=login&id=${users[i].id}`;
  }
}
loginSuspended
```

Comment: "*I need multiple return statements*" If this is your expectation, you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how `return` works in JavaScript.

Comment: You have also a syntaxError. The part of your comment `below)` is in another line on its own

Comment: `window.location.href = \`welkom.html?type=login&id=${users[i].id}\`;

      if (!userIsKnown) {` does not make sense. It will no go to the if since you change the location before it.

Comment: You need to pass back the values you want the main function have reference to.

Comment: Why do you validate multiple users simultaneously? For a Login function? This is extremely wrong. Get only ONE user from the database given a unique email (or username if usernames are unique (which is bad practice in any app)) (PS. try to write your code/comments/filenames in English. Might help a future developer, or someone giving you support, not necessarily from the Netherlands)

Comment: Also **never**, I mean it, **ever** store passwords in plaintext. Always compare the passwords over SSL using a hashing algorithm.

Comment: Also, you're setting `userIsKnown = true;` and just a bit after you're trying to check if `if (!userIsKnown) {` which makes no sense since it will always be `true`

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript login with user authentication

Validating users by ***Username*** is bad practice (UX-wise). Use something unique like an **Email**.

Regarding your code, there's many logical issues I tried to address in comments, here I'll focus in providing an arguably *better* solution.

**Split your code into reusable functions**, you need only a couple:

- an `authUser()` function that receives username and password and responds with an Object — which is part of your Application logic
- a Login handler function `loginHandler()` — which is part of the DOM events actions handlers

```js
// App: LOGIN

const DB_mockup = {
  users: [
    {id:11, email:"jon@example.com", password:"SHA256", username:"Jon", suspended: false},
    {id:17, email:"ann@example.com", password:"SHA256", username:"Ann", suspended: false},
    {id:28, email:"tom@example.com", password:"SHA256", username:"Tom", suspended: true},
  ]
};

/**
 * Get all users from database.
 * This is for DEMO ONLY to emulate a database Users table. 
 * WARNING! NEVER STORE PASSWORDS IN PLAINTEXT!
 * Also, this part should be done on the server-side.
 * @return {array} Users
 */
const getUsers = () => {
  // Get users from DB
  // @TODO: Get real DB users data
  return DB_mockup.users;
};

/**
 * User authentication
 * @param {string} email User submitted email
 * @param {string} password User submitted password
 * @return {object} auth data response object
 */
const authUser = (email, password) => {

  // 0. Define a commmon error response
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#client_error_responses
  // Pessimism rulez!
  const err = {
    code: 403,
    success: false,
    message: "invalid username or password",
  };

  // 1. Check if valid data is submitted
  if (!email || !password)
    return err;

  // 2. Get all users:
  const users = getUsers();

  // 3. Get temporarily a user that matches the provided Email
  const user = users.find((user) => user.email === email);

  // 4. Check if we got any user matching the email
  if (!user)
    return err;

  // 5. Check if passwords match
  // WARNING! THIS IS NOT THE RIGHT WAY TO DO IT. 
  // Salted and hashed passwords should be validated 
  // on server-side over an SSL connection!
  if (user.password !== password)
    return err;

  // 6. Chech if user is suspended
  if (user.suspended)
    return { ...err, code: 401, message: "user is suspended" };

  // 7. All went fine. Email and Password match
  // and user is not suspended. Authenticate user:
  
  // WARNING! Not the right way. Use cookies, server-side Session
  // localStorage.KEY = user.id;

  // Return a success Object instead of err
  return {
    code: 200,
    success: true,
    message: "user successfully authenticated",
    data: user,
  };
};


// DOM

/** Helper functions */
const EL = (sel, EL) => (EL || document).querySelector(sel);

/**
 * Login handler
 */
const loginHandler = () => {
  const EL_email = EL("#email");
  const EL_password = EL("#password");
  const EL_message = EL("#message");

  // Get authentication response:
  const authResponse = authUser(EL_email.value, EL_password.value);
  console.log(authResponse); // Demo only

  // Determine where to send the user
  // given the Auth data object response.
  //
  // SUCCESS:
  if (authResponse.success) {
    // location.assign(`welkom.html?type=login&id=${authResponse.data.id}`);
  }
  // ERRORS:
  // - Handle suspension:
  else if (authResponse.code === 401) {
    // location.assign(`suspended.html?type=login`);
  }
  // - Handle other errors like 403 etc:
  else {
    // Whatever we need
  }
  // ALWAYS:
  EL_message.textContent = authResponse.message;
  EL_message.classList.add("error", !authResponse.success);
};

EL("#login").addEventListener("click", loginHandler);
```

```css
#message:first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
.error { color: red; }
```

```html
<input id="email" type="text" value="tom@example.com">
<input id="password" type="password" value="SHA256">
<button id="login" type="button">LOGIN</button>
<div id="message"></div>
```

---

Now, to answer your exact question: *"How to invoke variables from other function in Javascript?"*

you make a function that `return`s your variables, usually as an Object holding your key/value pairs:

```js
const getDate = () => {

  // Do some stuff here 
  const date = Date.now();  // milliseconds timestamp
  
  // and than return something
  return {
    timestamp: date,
    message: "Here's your date",
    interested_in: "unicorns",
  };
};

const printDate = () => {  
  // Get variables from another function
  const {timestamp, message} = getDate();

  // and use them as you see fit
  console.log(`${message} ::: ${new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString()}`)
};

// Init
printDate();
```